# Building a tree from preorder in C++

Tags: c++, binary-tree, compression, preorder

I am working on a compression/decompression assignment. I'm trying to write a C++ method to build a tree using the following preorder traversal from the header of my compressed file:
001c1b01a01e1d
0 represents an internal node while 1 represents a leaf. Every time I create a node, I set the code of that node to either 0 or 1, because I will be using another method to decode the tree and it must know how to traverse down different sides by using these codes. Whenever I reach a 1 in the preorder traversal string, I set the node's "symbol" field to the following character in the preorder string. I can't get it to work though. Can anyone help? Here is my code ("bitsToRead" just represents the length of the preorder string so the method knows when to stop) Thanks!

```
void HCTree::buildFromHeader(ifstream& in, HCNode* n, int codeToUse) {

   if( bitsToRead > 0) {
      char c = in.get();
      bitsToRead--;
      if(c == '0') {
         n = new HCNode(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, codeToUse);
         if(rootSet == 0) {
            root = n;
            rootSet = true;
         }
         HCNode* left;
         n->c0 = left;
         HCNode* right;
         n->c1 = right;
         buildFromHeader(in, left, 0);
         buildFromHeader(in, right, 1);
      }
      else { 
         byte symbol = in.get();
         n = new HCNode(0, symbol, 0, 0, 0, codeToUse);
         bitsToRead--;
         n->c0 = n->c1 = NULL;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems changing

```
void HCTree::buildFromHeader(ifstream& in, HCNode* n, int codeToUse) {
```

to

```
void HCTree::buildFromHeader(ifstream& in, HCNode* &n, int codeToUse) {
```

will do the work.

Plus the `rootSet` logic can be omitted. You just call

```
buildFromHeader(in, root, codeToUse)
```

from the caller.

**EDIT:**

I misread your code in the first place. `n = new HCNode(0, symbol, 0, 0, 0, codeToUse);` is the code made me suggests to use a reference. Because what you want to do here is the changing the pointer passed from the leaf's ancestor (the `n->c0 = left` and `n->c1 = right` stuff). To make the whold thing work, in addition to the change above, change

```
HCNode* left;
n->c0 = left;
HCNode* right;
n->c1 = right;
buildFromHeader(in, left, 0);
buildFromHeader(in, right, 1);
```

to

```
buildFromHeader(in, n->c0, 0);
buildFromHeader(in, n->c1, 0);
```

This will let the callee to assign values *transparently* to pointers inside `struct` using references.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for helping, but it's not working.. Why did you suggest changing from HCNode* n to HCNode* &n ??

Comment: Sorry but I misread some part of your code, answer updated and hope it's correct now.

Comment: Thank you! I'm finally getting some output!